# Weird graphics issues after waking MacBook up

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, memory, graphics

After locking my Mac and waking it up a few hours later this is how it looks:

[image: Some weird stuff going on]

Also, some of the icons look weird after restarting the system (for example not fully rendered time machine icon: [image] )

**Hardware:** mid 2013 MacBook Air - i5 1,5GHz 128SSD, 8GB RAM.

I suspect one thing, however this is my first mac and I prefer not to mess around anymore: The problem started ocurring after I have disabled the swap.

Earlier I did research how much memory I use (<4GB RAM and ~2GB swap) and decided to remove the swap to force RAM usage.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Wow it has been four years and no one responded to you? Maybe I can revive this since I am having a similar issue... When I open my lid, I get that same distorted image on my screen but it is only for a split second. this started after I changed my resolution to a higher resolution so my guess is that the laptop is switching between the onboard graphics and the dedicated GPU? it is not stuck like yours but it does show the same look for a split second. If anyone knows the cause please let us know. My computer is the early 2013 macbook pro retina 2.7 i7 16gb ram intel HD Graphics 4000 1536mb(on

Comment: Well I use swap and everything works fine since then :D Hopefully someone will help you with your issue.

Comment: I have nearly the same issue with my 2017 MacBook Pro 13" after waking it from sleep. The only difference is, the whole screen is distorted like yours, with nothing to see. After 1 or 2 seconds everything seems to be ok.